# Visual Studio не видит Registry из Microsoft.Win32

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

У меня проблема, я хочу на c# прочитать реестр, я импортирую `using Microsoft.Win32;` и из неё уже `Registry` но оно его не видит [image: первый скрин] [image: второй скрин]

вот содерживое csproj файла

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Тип приложения какой? Версия дотнета какая? Покажите содержимое .cproj файла.

Comment: @aepot где его посмотреть, версия дотнета .NET Core 3.1, но могу поставить .NET 5.0

Comment: В каталоге с проектом, для .NET 5 и .NET Core 3.1 решение вашей проблемы будет выглядеть по-разному. Так что вы заранее и окончательно определитесь.

Comment: @aepot тогда это .NET Core 3.1

Comment: отредактируйте пост, вставьте текстом содержимое cproj файла

Comment: @aepot отредактировал, вставил